# Power on pi and cpu heats up very fast

Tags: cable, ide

When I power up pi cpu heats up to 40-50 c and red, green leds are on, tried to use other sd cards but nothing, last what i did tried to connect gpio pins with ide cable.

Comment: Pi does not boot

Comment: Which model of Pi?  What sort of IDE cable did you use?

Comment: B+ 1.2 and 40 pin ide hard drive cable

Comment: Modern IDE cables have 80 wires (still 40 pins).  Do the individual wires look very slim?  Unfortunately if it was an 80 wire cable the Pi may be dead.  It's not just a straight through cable, some pins are interconnected.  The gpios may have been shorted and that could have killed the Pi.

Comment: Yes it's 80 wire ide, I think it's dead and not reperable :'(

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.  I almost did the same.  I got a cable out but luckily read a warning post and didn't fit the cable.

Comment: I would accept that the Pi is dead - if it's getting that hot that quickly, it's toasted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern IDE cables have 80 wires (still 40 pins). Do the individual wires look very slim? Unfortunately if it was an 80 wire cable the Pi may be dead. It's not just a straight through cable, some pins are interconnected. The gpios may have been shorted and that could have killed the Pi. –  joan